# Removing PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer bean Autowiring doesn't work

Tags: java, spring

What is the purpose of adding "PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" as a bean in spring? . As far as I researched it says when you name your property file as application.properties, spring will automatically take the file when it is in src/main/resources Folder. Having so, when I remove the Bean Declaration for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, it says couldn't autowire the property.

What am I missing, Why isn't it working without PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Sample 1:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "application.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { Some Package })
public class ApplicationConfig {

    ApplicationConfig() {

    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Sample 1 works fine, When I remove `@PropertySources` and `@PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean since spring will pick up `application.properties` automatically, it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you remove `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` ? Spring will automatically initialize that bean if it's present in classpath

Comment: removing the manually added bean for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says when you name your property file as application.properties,
>   spring will automatically take the file when it is in
>   src/main/resources Folder

As I know - this is correct only for Spring Boot.
For spring core you should define you prps in contxet.
There are several ways. 
In xml

```
< context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

or using Java annotation

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

It's not necessary to define `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` since Spring 4.3RC2

Comment: even after using @PropertySource annotation without the bean for PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about `@Configuration`. Try to add it.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14140 looks like this is a bug, which will be fixed in spring version 4.3RC2

Comment: Correct! Changing the spring version in pom.xml worked! Thanks

Comment: @ChinniahAnnamalai no problem. I'he added information about version to my answer